# Angular secondary routes - Can't navigate & clear secondary route in the same navigate call?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I'm having an issue where it appears I can't navigate to a new route, and clear an outlet / secondary route at the same time.

Calling those two actions separately works - but feels like a workaround. Is there good reason why they should be done as two calls? Or is there an error in my implementation? Or should I file it as a GitHub issue?

These work independently:

```
// Navigate to `/second`
this._router.navigate(['/second']);

// Clears the `popup` outlet
this._router.navigate(['', {outlets: { popup: null }}]);
```

I thought this should work, but it doesn't clear the outlet:

```
this._router.navigate(['/second', {outlets: { popup: null }}]);
```

My current work-around is:

```
this._router.navigate(['', {outlets: { popup: null }}]).then(() => { this._router.navigate(['second']); } );
```

I've created a [plnkr proof of concept](http://embed.plnkr.co/hvi6Ry/) - navigation code is in `global-popup.component.ts`

Comment: Did the answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to explicitly set primary outlet path like below,

```
public closeAndNav_singleCall() {
   return this._router.navigate([{
     outlets: { 
       primary : ['second'],
       popup: null 
     }
   }]);
}
```

Updated your [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/VT7Xr9?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Cool - though I'm finding that setting `primary` will URL encode the `/` slash, so is it not intended to handle absolute paths? (e.g.: Setting `primary : ['/areaTwo/second']` will navigate to `%2FareaTwo=%2Fsecond`. I'll make a plnkr this evening.

Comment: you may use `primary : ['areaTwo','second']`

Answer (score 1):

The above works when the primary navigation is absolute on the primary route.
The problem I am having is: how to do a relative navigation on the primary route, while clearing the secondary route.

I have tried different combinations but none seem to work:

starting at
`https://localhost:4200/one/two(popup:some/other)`

```
    this.router.navigate([
      '',
      {
        outlets: {
          primary: ['areaTwo', 'second'],
          popup: null,
        },
      },
    ]);
```

ending at `https://localhost:4200/areaTwo/second`

So it clears the secondary popup, and it does an absolute navigation.

starting at
`https://localhost:4200/one/two(popup:some/other)`

```
    this.router.navigate([
      {
        outlets: {
          primary: ['areaTwo', 'second'],
          popup: null,
        },
      },
    ], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });
```

ending at `https://localhost:4200/one/two/areaTwo/second(popup:some/other)`

So it does a relative on the primary, but does not clear the secondary.

But how can we do something like:

starting at
`https://localhost:4200/one/two(popup:some/other)`

ending at `https://localhost:4200/one/two/areaTwo/second`